# Golang Mongodb %!(EXTRA

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to marshal a struct into JSON and then insert it into my Mongo database, but keep on getting this error: `%!(EXTRA main.Test={575590180 Me})`. What am I doing wrong? I took this code exactly from another project I worked on which could insert documents without any problems.

```
package main

import (
    "utils"
    "hash/fnv"
    "log"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Test struct {
    Id   uint32
    Name string
}

func ConnectDB() *mgo.Session {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return session
}

func SaveMgoDoc(dbName string, collectionName string, file Test) bool {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer session.Close()

    fileJson, err := json.Marshal(file)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to marshal struct to json...\n", file)
        return false
    }

    collection := session.DB(dbName).C(collectionName)
    err         = collection.Insert(&fileJson)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to insert doc into database...\n", file)
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func hash(s string) uint32 {
        h := fnv.New32a()
        h.Write([]byte(s))
        return h.Sum32()
}

func main() {
    utils.SaveMgoDoc("mydb", "mydoc", Test{hash("Me"), "Me"})
}
```

Comment: @old_mountain That works. Sorry for the dumb question. I assumed that all objects must be JSON to be inserted into MongoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Insert` expects a pointer to a struct, not a `json` string. So, in this case, just use:

```
err = collection.Insert(&file)
```